# How can I do a Wild Card search on email addresses in Audience Manager through the Tridion 2013 CME?

Tags: 2013, cme, audience-manager

We are unable to do wild card searches for email addresses in Audience Manager in the Tridion 2013 CME.

Has anyone implemented a solution to this or does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: This is listed under 'Unanswered' because you haven't accepted any answers yet. Could you either elaborate on why the current answer is not clear enough (so that we can clarify and get some better answers), or mark it as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no out-of-the-box solution to that. There are rather large performance considerations when doing partial searches over millions of Contacts (and supporting different databases). So it hasn't happened yet, as it hasn't been a high priority.